# How to enable sharing of web site on localhost?

Tags: web-applications, iis-7, web-hosting, user-accounts

I tried to enable my site on loclhost to be accessed from other computers but i can't find a way to do this. I have tried to add shareing to "Internet Guest Account" but that doesn't work either. I just can't forse it to enable access from my other computer.

[alt text http://img162.imageshack.us/img162/7379/sharee.jpg](http://img162.imageshack.us/img162/7379/sharee.jpg)

Comment: Which web-techonology and web-server used by your local website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allow web service hosting out of your windows firewall which is in your control panel.

File Sharing doesn't enter into it unless you are wishing to share your website's code with other members on your network.

**Steps to allow localhost web service hosting**

1. Open Start Menu and click Control Panel
2. Click Security (or if you are in classic view click Windows Firewall and goto step 4)
3. Click 'Allow a program through windows firewall'
4. Click Change Settings
5. Click the Exceptions tab
6. Ensure there is a check aside World Wide Web Services (HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @David Christiansen above is outdated.

In Windows 10 or above you should go:

1. Firewall Settings
2. Advanced Settings
3. Create a new `Inboud Rule` for your desired port