# Connect to the PC's local host through usb cable on android device

Tags: android, iis

I'm debuging an android application using my android smartphone (Sony Experia) and I need to connect to the computer's local host through the android app I'm developing. I tried several methods (USB tethering, Wifi hotspot) but I couldn't achieve it. Please support me with a solution. I know that simply 10.0.2.2 is working well on the android AVD but I've no idea about real devices.

I'm using Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) as my server and the web application is also running well. I don't know whether the firewall is blocking the port or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

- Unplug all the network cables on the computer and turn off your wifi.
- Turn off the wifi on your Xperia.
- Connect your Xperia to your computer via USB Turn on "USB Tethering" in the android menu. (Under networks-> more...-> Tethering and portable hotspot")
- Get the IP of your computer that has been assigned by the USB
  tether cable. (open command prompt and type "ipconfig" then look
  for the IP that the USB  network adapter has assigned, It is Under 'Ethernet Adapter Local Area Connection' title. The Value for the IPv4 address is the One you need.)
- Open a browser on the PC using the IP    address found instead of
  localhost to test. i.e.

  ```
   http://192.168.1.1/myWebSite
  ```
- Open a browser on the android and it should work.

If it is working on your PC but not in your device, You have to allow your http through firewall.

Follow [How to enable sharing of web site on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205249/how-to-enable-sharing-of-web-site-on-localhost) to do it.

Comment: I followed your instructions. When I use PC's browser, it works well, But when I use the android device, It's not available. Is it a firewall problem?

Comment: I solved the problem, I had to allow local host through my firewall as well. After doing it it works! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205249/how-to-enable-sharing-of-web-site-on-localhost helped me to do it.